# Height 100vh - height of other element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
document.querySelector('.saved').style.height = '100vh' - document.querySelector('.header').offsetHeight + 'px';
```

I want to make the `div.saved` have height 100vh - height of `div.header`. The code on top doesn't work. What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use build-in css [function calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```
document.querySelector('.saved').style.height = 'calc(100vh - ' +   document.querySelector('.header').offsetHeight + 'px)';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a calculate call in CSS. Your code does not make the browser aware of the fact that it has to calculate the height of the element.
Something like

```
document.querySelector('.saved').style.height = 'calc(100vh - ' +  document.querySelector('.header').offsetHeight + 'px)';
```

should work.